# Windows enforces READ-ONLY .text section, even thus disabled by the ld linker

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, gdb, nasm

In the toy program below, I declare a variable in the .text section and writes to it, which gives a segmentation-fault, since the `.text` section is marked as READ-ONLY:

```
Breakpoint 1, 0x00401000 in start ()
(gdb) disassemble
Dump of assembler code for function start:
=> 0x00401000 <+0>:     movl   $0x2,0x40100a
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) stepi

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00401000 in start ()
(gdb)
```

Here is the `objdump` output:

```
test.exe:     file format pei-i386

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .text         0000001f  00401000  00401000  00000200  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  1 .idata        00000014  00402000  00402000  00000400  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
```

However, linking using the `--omagic` switch (disables READ-ONLY `.text` section) yields the following results:

```
ld --omagic -o test.exe test.obj

test.exe:     file format pei-i386

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .text         0000001f  00401000  00401000  000001d0  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, CODE
  1 .idata        00000014  00402000  00402000  000003d0  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
```

But debugging this using `GDB` gives the following (weird) results:

```
Breakpoint 1, 0x00401000 in start ()
(gdb) disassemble
Dump of assembler code for function start:
=> 0x00401000 <+0>:     dec    %ebp
   0x00401001 <+1>:     pop    %edx
   0x00401002 <+2>:     nop
   0x00401003 <+3>:     add    %al,(%ebx)
   0x00401005 <+5>:     add    %al,(%eax)
   0x00401007 <+7>:     add    %al,(%eax,%eax,1)
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) stepi
0x00401001 in start ()
(gdb) stepi
0x00401002 in start ()
(gdb) stepi
0x00401003 in start ()
(gdb) stepi
0x00401005 in start ()
(gdb) stepi

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00401005 in start ()
(gdb)
```

First of all, I still get a segmentation fault, but the assembly code has also changed structure?

How can I link the `.text` section as writable on `Windows 10 x64`?

**Toy program:**

```
    BITS 32

    section .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov [var], dword 2
var:    dd 0
    ret
```

Comment: In the r+w linking case the "file ofs" for .text is `000001d0`, ie. -48 compared to first case. Can you check what opcodes are at `0x00401030`, if there's that missing `mov [var],2`? Or search between `0x00401000` -> `0x00401030`, if it is hidden somewhere there (so somehow the "file ofs" is wrong then). But I have no idea what is causing the "file ofs" movement. Maybe `--file-alignment 512` with `--omagic` can be related (but I haven't touched `ld` low level for years, so I'm just putting up random things from docs. Hopefully somebody will have real answer :) ).

Comment: Or even simpler, check the binary in .exe (in hex view), if at that file ofs is the `mov [var],2` opcode, or if it's somewhere later, and how much. That may be indication that `ld` is for some reason putting "wrong" `file ofs` into header. (ld has probably good logical reasons why that result is as is, just not following your expectations)

Comment: Does it make any difference if you use a program that *could* work?  i.e. that doesn't have the `dd 0` before the `ret`.  Or at least store some NOPs.  (`02 00 00 00` decodes as `add    (%eax),%al`; `add    %al,(%eax)`).  I *think* current x86 hardware will detect that self-modifying code and run the newly-stored instructions.  Anyway, I agree your second gdb results look weird.

Comment: Another way to make a Windows executable with writeable text: [**use `link /SECTION:.text,EWR`**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38880310/224132)

Comment: @PeterCordes - Thank you, I will definitely try this. Maybe it works better than using "ld"? Have you tested using "link"?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen: I don't even have Windows.  I just remembered seeing that question a couple days ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, `ld` completely changes the PE executable linked using the `--omagic` option.

A quick comparison of the files using the `cmp` utility shows:

```
 137 177 222
 141   0 320
 142   6   5
 213   0 320
 214   2   1
 217 142 205
 218 154 353
 397   0 320
 398   2   1
 437   0 320
 438   4   3
 465   0 307
```

...

So lots of differences, although `ld` should in principle only change the sections flags of the section header (.text), i.e.  set the flag `IMAGE_SCN_MEM_WRITE`.

Changing the flags manually using HxD, i.e. setting byte at offset 0x19F to 0xE0 solves the  issue...

[image]

A trial run of the program with interchanged order of `var` and `ret` (otherwise the program crash):

```
Breakpoint 1, 0x00401000 in start ()
(gdb) disassemble
Dump of assembler code for function start:
=> 0x00401000 <+0>:     movl   $0x2,0x40100b
   0x0040100a <+10>:    ret
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) stepi
0x0040100a in start ()
(gdb) disassemble
Dump of assembler code for function start:
   0x00401000 <+0>:     movl   $0x2,0x40100b
=> 0x0040100a <+10>:    ret
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) x/wx var
0x40100b <var>: 0x00000002
(gdb)
```

and we see things work as expected.

My conclusion is that `ld` somehow generates a badly formatted PE executable, and I see that @RossRidge has the answer to this (`ld` doesn't respect the file alignment of sections).

Answer (score 3):

The `--omagic` flag is causing the GNU linker to generate a bad PECOFF executable. Sections must aligned in the file with a minimum file alignment of 512 bytes, but the linker puts the `.text` section at file offset of 0x1d0.

Instead of using the `--omagic` flag, generate your executable normally and then use `objcopy` to change the flags in the section header:

```
ld -o test-tmp.exe test.obj
$(OBJCOPY) --set-section-flags .text=code,data,alloc,contents,load test-tmp.exe test.exe
```

Comment: why do you set the section flags to "data"? I see it doesn't work without, but a flag is introduced that was not found in "objdump" output initially?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen The `data` flag needs to be set in order to make the section writable,

Comment: But why? If I edit using HxD, the resulting set of flags is not the same: the read-only flag is removed, and no data flag set, and it works.

Comment: So is this a bug in "ld"?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen did you try that `--file-alignment 512` suggestion? If it does fix the behaviour of `--omagic`. I wouldn't count it as "bug" of `ld`, as the `--omagic` in docs has that drop of alignment described, so it's just doing what is documented. Although probably not so much useful.

Comment: No, can try it. But the other tips worked perfectly. I will try yours out now :-)