# How to make code sections writable at runtime

Tags: c, permissions

I am studying malware in my information security class and have been learning a about malware which will change the permissions to its own code sections so that they are writable, modify the code, and then change the permissions back. I thought this was interesting and wanted to make a demo demonstrating this type of functionality. I found [this tutorial](https://shanetully.com/2013/12/writing-a-self-mutating-x86_64-c-program/) on how to accomplish this on a Unix systems, but was wondering what APIs or system calls are used to do this on a Windows computer.

Comment: You may look at this post "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879627/is-it-possible-to-make-writeable-variables-in-text-segment-using-db-directive-i/38880310" one of the contributor suggest using VirtualProtect function

Comment: @OlivierPellier-Cuit This looks like it is leading me to the answer. Thanks for your help! I'd upvote your comment, but I don't have that privilege yet.