# SIGSEGV on simple move register to memory in NASM

Tags: memory, segmentation-fault, nasm, cpu-registers, mov

I must be missing something very basic here. Searched SO but could not find the answer to this particular question. Here's my NASM code:

```
%include "io64.inc"

section .text
    myvar db "This is not working", 0
global CMAIN
CMAIN:
    mov rbp, rsp; for correct debugging
    ;write your code here
    xor rax, rax
    mov [myvar], rax
    ret
```

It crashes on the `move [myvar], rax` line with SIGSEGV. I am simply trying to store some zeroes at that address.

Thanks!

PS: Using SASM to build / run / debug with 64 bit option ticked (default settings otherwise), on Windows 10 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> section .text
>    myvar db "This is not working", 0
> ```

Section `.text` is an executable section without write permissions. This is done to prevent some kinds of vulnerabilities. You should either place your `myvar` into a writable section, e.g. `.data` (if the variable should live for the whole duration of program execution), have the variable on the stack (if it's not supposed to outlive the function where it's created), or change `.text` to be writable (not recommended for security reasons, but [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38879627/673852)).

Comment: Yes, that was it, thanks Ruslan! One thing I noticed (and it took me a while to figure it out) is that the `.data` section has to be at the end. If I have the `.data` section after the `.text` section and before the actual code, it still crashes. If I move the `.data` section to the end of the program, it works. I am sure there's an explanation for it.

Either way, many thanks!

Comment: @Gec: You can put `section .data` first, then the data you want to have, and then change to `section .text` and that should work. The last `section` directive before your actual code needs to activate the text section.